# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage vs glTexImage2D

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, avfoundation

I have an iOS app where I'm reading a video from `AVFoundation` and loading each video frame into an OpenGL texture and displaying it on screen in a `GLKView`.

I have no problem copying the video buffer for each frame:

```
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [someAVPlayerItemVideoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
```

But when I load the video into openGL I get different results depending on which method I use.  My understanding from watching Apple's WWDC 2011 Session 414 Advances in OpenGL video is that the new `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` function should be faster than just reading in the pixel buffer via `glTexImage2D`.  However, when using a shader program with a lot of calculations, I get the same frame rate no matter which method I use.  Furthermore, `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` is actually giving me a strange 'blocky' distortion while `glTexImage2D` does not.  The distortion seems as though random blocks on the screen do not update with the latest frame.

Here is code I'm using to create the texture with the `CVOpenGLESTexture` method:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef videoFrameTexture = NULL;
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);    
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, videoTextureCache, buffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer), GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &videoTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(videoFrameTexture));
CVBufferRelease(buffer);    
CFRelease(videoFrameTexture);
```

And here is the alternative way in which I use to load via `glTexImage2D`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer)/4, CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer));
```

Why am I getting strange distortion and no better frame rate by using `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`?

Comment: At what part of that video did you find out that function is faster? Are you calling this "texture update" on the same thread as your drawing is happening? And why are you not using glTexSubImage to update your texture?

Comment: @MaticOblak I see the strange distortion almost immediately.  
The texture update is happening on the main thread.  I'm not using glTexSubImage because my understanding is that glTexSubImage only updates part of a texture.  My entire texture is just one frame of the video.  When there's a new frame of the video, I replace the texture.

Comment: I *think* the issue is with calling CFRelease and CVBufferRelease immediately.  Since I'm using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(), OpenGL is trying to read the texture directly from memory.  While OpenGL is doing this, my code is already on the next frame.  If I create my own CVPixelBufferRef queue, and cycle through it, I'm able to get rid of the 'blocky' distortion.

Comment: @GingerBreadMane Store double or triple buffers of the pixel data and cycle through. I had a similar problem.

Comment: @JustinMeiners That's what you did to solve the blocky distortion issue?  That's what I ended up doing too.

Comment: @GingerBreadMane yes, I used a triple buffer and that solved it for me. https://github.com/justinmeiners/image-sequence-streaming